# Xcode - HitTesting returns 3 times

Tags: xcode, events, nslog, hittest

I have a UIView subclass where hitTest: withEvent: is overridden. Every time a hit test registers, the view logs its tag.

Ex: *Click*

Console:
You Touched View: 3
You Touched View: 3
You Touched View: 3

My question: Why does it do it three times? I need it to trigger something other than an NSLog and I'm afraid that it will trigger that three times also. I could easily work around the triple trigger, but I was wondering if there was a better explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you log the event information as well as the uiview's tag.  It could be getting called by multiple events - touchDown, touchUp, etc.

Comment: That was correct, I simply changed to use touchesBegan, ended, etc and it works fine.